# Can I use ps aux, along with -o etime?

Tags: ps

I want to list all the processes what are running, which I'm doing using either `ps aux`, or `ps auxf`, but I also want to get the elapsed time for all of them. I've seen the command `ps -o etime,cmd`, which displays the elapsed time, and the command, but it doesn't seem to list all of them. Can I combine the `aux(f)` and `-o etime` at all?

Comment: `ps axf -o pid,user,etime,cmd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My apologies,
I figured out that the columns are overwritten by the `-o`.

Here is what you were looking for:

```
ps -e -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,command,etime,euid
```

Comment: Just a note, that didn't list them all, I needed to add `-ax` to the command to get all the processes. But other than that, good answer :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to see all processes along with their elapsed time, you can use `-A` (or its synonym `-e`).

So, something like: `ps -A -o etime,cmd`

From the `ps` manual page:

> **-A** Select all processes.  Identical to **-e**.